# Unexpected behavior when passing an attribute as torch.LongTensor in Pytorch Geometric

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I have a Hetero Graph dataset where I need to store a scalar number namely `relation` for each graph. The DataLoader works fine if I pass the value of `relation` as an `int` or `torch.tensor` but when I pass `relation` as `torch.LongTensor`, the value of `relation` on each batch becomes unpredictable.
This is how I create the dataset:

```
data = HeteroData()
# for example, relation = 0
data['relation'] = int(relation)
data['relation'] = torch.tensor(relation)
data['relation'] = torch.LongTensor(relation)
```

For example, with `batch_size = 8`, when passing relation as `int` or `torch.tensor`, then a batch looks like this

```
HeteroDataBatch(
  relation=[8],
  entity={
    x=[12661, 15],
    batch=[12661],
    ptr=[9],
  },
...
```

Notice that relation is a vector of length 8 which is expected.
But when passing relation as int or torch.LongTensor (batch_size is still 8), the batch looks like this

```
HeteroDataBatch(
  relation=[39],
  entity={
    x=[12661, 15],
    batch=[12661],
    ptr=[9],
  },
```

Relation is now a vector of length 39, when I print out the actual value of `batch['relation']`, they are all zeros. I wonder what caused this unexpected behavior.